# Passing values to html template when using django-floppyforms

Tags: django, django-floppyforms

I'm using django-floppyforms. 
How do I pass some values to the html template?
(Both for initializing a field, and for simple printing).
The code below explains the setting:

models.py:

```
class ContactMessage(models.Model):    
    msg_sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="sent_messages")
    msg_receiver = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="received_messages")
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing)
    msg_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    msg_body = models.TextField()
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^listing/(?P<listing_id>\d+)/reply/$', views.ReplyListingView.as_view(), name='reply_listing'),
```

views.py:

```
class ReplyListingView(CreateView):
    model = ContactMessage
    form_class = CreateContactMessageForm
```

forms.py:

```
class CreateContactMessageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ContactMessage

        exclude = ['msg_sender',
                   'msg_receiver',
                   'listing',
                  ]

        widgets = {
            'msg_title': forms.TextInput({"value": ????}),
            'msg_body': forms.Textarea,
        }
```

contactmessage_form.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
      <p>USER: {{request.user}} 
         SENDER: {{ form.sender }} 
         RECEIVER: {{ form.receiver }}
         LISTING: {{ form.listing }}
      </p>
      <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}
        <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Send" />
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onClick="window.history.back();">
                Cancel
        </button>
      </form>
  </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

So:

Suppose in a certain context, I know the listing, the sender, and the receiver (background explanation: The URL has the listing_id, so the listing's title and owner are known; and furthermore the sender should be the current logged-in user).

Now I want to display a ReplyListingView, pass those three values to it, then have it show the CreateContactMessageForm such that:

1. The msg_title widget is pre-filled with the value of the "title" field of the given listing (i.e. instead of the "????" part in the code above)
2. I can access the values of the sender, receiver, and listing fields in the html (the `<p>USER:...</p>` part).

How can I do that?

I hope the question is clear enough.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming floppyforms works just like django forms (and it looks that way), just use initial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values

Comment: As you can see above, I am not directly creating the form, but telling the view to use the form: 

    `form_class = CreateContactMessageForm`

so I don't know if your solutions applies

Answer (score 0):

There is an initial View variable.

Have a look at this site they have all view methods and variables:
http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.5/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/

You can also override the method that instantiate the form and add initial

Answer (score 0):

```
class ReplyListingView(CreateView):

    model = ContactMessage
    form_class = CreateContactMessageForm

    #add this line to the view
    initial={"field_name":"value"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the title, you should pass initial data to the form using `get_initial`.

Regarding other non-form stuff, your view should inject it to the template via `get_context_data`.

```
class ReplyListingView(CreateView):
    model = ContactMessage
    form_class = CreateContactMessageForm

    def get_initial(self):
        d = super(ReplyListingView, self).get_initial()
        d['title'] = "blah"
        return d

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        d = super(ReplyListingView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        d['foo'] = 'bar'
        return d
```